# How to deal with Densheild to drywall transition disparity

Tags: drywall, tile, transition, porcelain

I'm in the process of tiling now (*porcelain tile*).
I noticed that the seam between the Densheild and the drywall is  slightly not even.

Do I need to use the all purpose compound (*used for dry wall*) to try making them even.

Or shall I use the thinset mortar that I will use for tiling?

Or shall I leave it like this?

These seams will be covered by the tile at the end.

I'm going to use this thinset
(*Custom Building Products  Natural Stone and Large Tile 50 lbs. White Premium Mortar*)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the difference appears to be minimal and you can just leave it.

Take a tile and place in on the denshield so it overlaps the drywall and place the edge trim behind the tile, if the gap between the back of the edge trim and the drywall is an 1/8" or less it will be fine.

A little extra thinset will fill the difference in the depth.

The extruded aluminum edging may not sit flush or down tight to the drywall but that can be hidden with a bead of caulking.